# Open Entry in a Modal

Tags: templating

Unsure how to go about doing this. I'm looking to open a related entry in a modal on the same page. In an area, I have a list of houses. On click, I would like the user to open a modal and load the corresponding entry inside it.

Is there an easier way to do this other than AJAX loading it in?

Comment: Hey, are we talking front-end here?

Comment: Yep. Can't see anywhere about loading Entries in a modal on a click etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax is probably the easiest way when using something like [Fancybox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#iframe):

```
<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="yoursite.com/houses/house-slug" href="javascript:;">
    House page
</a>
```

If your house page has content you want to hide when viewed in the modal you can detect whether or not Ajax was used to request the page:

```
{% if not craft.app.request.isAjax %}
    Your header code
{% endif }
```

You could also just include the house content on the page, but hidden and use [fancybox to reveal it](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#inline). This is possibly more accessible.

Comment: For the Q/A, would it be possible to add integration without fancybox?

Comment: For sure! Fancybox is a simple solution, but the principles would be the same if you were to custom code it.